# Cooking ribs weirdly?

Tags: sous-vide, ribs

So my brother who's pretty inexperienced brined his ribs, smoked them for an hour, put it back in the brine/fridge, and plans on sous vide+searing them. Is there danger in putting the cooked pork back in the brine if he uses sous vide? I told him how unnecessary his steps/processes were, but he's stubborn. I ask this bc I worry for his health.

Comment: Where did he come up with this idea? Just a random experiment? I agree with your "weird" descriptor but the only part that screams unsafe to me is putting hot, partially cooked meat into the fridge. Was it a cold smoke or a hot smoke? Was the meat actually cooked to a level of doneness? (Circa 145 degrees F+)

Comment: Also, was this presumably par-cooked meat returned to the _same_ brine, presumably including uncooked pork juice?

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with the brine, smoke, sous vide process as long as he pays attention to typical/safe temperatures. I would sous vide then smoke and probably return to a hot grill, rather than sear, but that is personal preference. What would be unusual would be a return to the brine after the smoking.  While it could be made safe from a food-safety standpoint (new brine...well-chilled...), I don't think that would be desirable or all that beneficial. Have him take a look here for detailed tips: https://www.chefsteps.com/classes/barbecue/#/dry-style-baby-back-ribs